# Issue with unwanted Scroll bar

Tags: html, css

The problem I am having is that I have a margin or a container somewhere that is creating an unwanted scroll bar horizontally on the bottom of my webpages. I am using my contact page since it is my page with the least amount of content, even though I am having the issue across all of my other 5 pages linked on this website. I know it will be something simple and would love an extra pair of eyes who could maybe shed some light onto where the issue is. Thanks in advance. Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide for further details. Thanks in advance.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>index.html</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><link rel="preconnect" 
    href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    
    

    <div class="IMGLogo">
    <img src="images/RJL photography_Logo.svg" alt="LOGO" width="370.026" height="65.492" ></div>
    
    
    <div id="wrapper">      

    <nav role="navigation">
    <div id="menuToggle">
    <!--
    A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click reciever,
    so you can use the :checked selector on it.
    -->
    <input type="checkbox" />
    
    <!--
    Some spans to act as a hamburger.
    
    They are acting like a real hamburger,
    not that McDonalds stuff.
    -->
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    
    <!--
    Too bad the menu has to be inside of the button
    
    -->
    <ul id="menu">
     <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="projects.html"><li>Projects</li></a>
      <a href="lofts.html"><li>Lofts</li></a>
      <a href="balcony.html"><li>Balcony/Rooftop</li></a>
      <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact</li></a>
     
    </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>

    
    </div>  
    <div>
    
    

    <main>
    <br>
        
    <br><h1>Contact</h1>
    
    <p class="pbox"> The folks at RJL Photography are eager to make your moments last a lifetime. Inquire 
    below.</p>
         
        
    <!-- Add icon library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- 
   awesome.min.css">

   <div class="card">
   <img src="images/New/Contact/RyanBio.JPG" alt="Ryan Bio" style="width:100%">
   <h1>Ryan Luber</h1>
   <p class="title">CEO & Founder, RJL Photography</p>
    <p>Frederick, MD</p>
   <p>443-222-3333</p>
    <p>RJLPhoto@RJLP.COM</p>
   <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
  
   </div>   

        <br>
        
        <div class="container">
    <form action="action_page.php">

    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
      
      <label for="pnumber">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text"
             id="pnumber"
             name="phonenumber"
             placeholder="Your phone number..">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Description of your desired Photoshoot." 
    style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
    </div>
     
    
    
    </main> 


    
    <!--wrapper--></div>
    <footer>&#169; RJLPhotography 2020 </footer>
    </html>
```

```
wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    align-content: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 30;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

article {
    background-image: url("../images/BAR.svg");
    width: 82%;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}

h2 {
    height: 10em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: -200px;
}


/* Container holding the image and the text */

.container {
    position: relative;
}


/* Bottom right text */

.text-block {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

body {
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    /* make it look decent enough */
    background: white;
    color: gray;
}

.IMGLogo {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 370.026px;
    height: 65.492px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: -40px;
}

p.pbox {
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-right: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

img {
    /*display: block;
     object-fit:cover;
    */
    width: 80%;
    height: 90%;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.center {
    /*display: block;*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 76%;
}

main {
    padding-left: 65px;
    position: static;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

#BARcenter {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    left: 60px;
    z-index: 50;
}

#BARcenter img {
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
}

#menuToggle {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 130px;
    left: 30px;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    right: auto;
}

#menuToggle a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#menuToggle a:hover {
    color: tomato;
}

#menuToggle input {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    /* hide this */
    z-index: 2;
    /* and place it over the hamburger */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}


/*
 * Just a quick hamburger
 */

#menuToggle span {
    display: block;
    width: 33px;
    height: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background: #cdcdcd;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 1;
    transform-origin: 4px 0px;
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}


/* 
 * Transform all the slices of hamburger
 * into a crossmark.
 */

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
    background: #232323;
}


/*
 * But let's hide the middle one.
 */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}


/*
 * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
 */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}


/*
 * Make this absolute positioned
 * at the top left of the screen
 */

#menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
    padding: 50px;
    padding-top: 125px;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)!important;
    list-style-type: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}

#menu li {
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
}


/*
 * And let's slide it in from the left
 */

#menuToggle input:checked~ul {
    transform: none;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.title {
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
}

button {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: black;
}

button:hover,
a:hover {
    opacity: 0.4;
}


/* Style inputs with type="text", select elements and textareas */

input[type=text],
select,
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    padding: 12px;
    /* Some padding */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* Rounded borders */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
    margin-top: 6px;
    /* Add a top margin */
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    /* Bottom margin */
    resize: vertical/* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
}


/* Style the submit button with a specific background color etc */

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/* When moving the mouse over the submit button, add a darker green color */

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}


/* Add a background color and some padding around the form */

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
}

#myBtn {
    display: none;
    /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed;
    /* Fixed/sticky position */
    bottom: 0px;
    /* Place the button at the bottom of the page */
    left: 30px;
    /* Place the button 30px from the right */
    z-index: 99;
    /* Make sure it does not overlap */
    border: none;
    /* Remove borders */
    outline: none;
    /* Remove outline */
    background-color: black;
    /* Set a background color */
    color: white;
    /* Text color */
    cursor: pointer;
    /* Add a mouse pointer on hover */
    padding: 25px;
    /* Some padding */
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* Rounded corners */
    font-size: 18px;
    /* Increase font size */
}

#myBtn:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    /* Add a dark-grey background on hover */
}
```

Comment: anyone else able to shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

On your main tag remove
padding-left: 65px;

and on your MenuToggle remove
left: 30px;

That fixes your issue of having an horizontal scroll bar.

You will then have to have a play about with your hamburger menu and contact text.
Try using position absolute rather than relative on your menuToggle.

Comment: Perfect, I will try those and report back. Thanks for the insite.

Comment: overflow-x did not work. because it actually just cut the content off on the right side where it is overflowing. Would you suggest trying to set a container, and margin or something of that sort for the content in that it overflowing?

Comment: Could you please post your css and then we can see what is going on. I think its because your container or form width will be too big.

Comment: I have updated the css now sorry for the delay.

Comment: If it worked for you Ryan Luber can you please accept the answer. I spent my time to help you so would appreciate that if it has fixed your issue then for you to click the green tick so it helps my reputation. Thank you.